# How to make table fit window in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I would like to make my table always fit the window.

I managed to make it fit the window but I want it to leave some space on the right margin as it does on the left margin. Another problem is that if the table had the width smaller than the window it will auto generate an empty column, something that i don't want.

I have tried to initialize the scene with vbox and make vbox grow automatically but I want it to leave the same margin that it leaves on the left.

```
    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    vbox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
    stage.setTitle("Market");
    stage.setWidth(700);
    stage.setHeight(650);
```

//*code*

```
vbox.setSpacing(10);
vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
vbox.getChildren().addAll(head, table, hb);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

And here is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/fuDQsqLz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adjust the Padding of the VBox.

The constructor of the Insets goes like this :

```
public Insets(top, right, bottom, left) { ... }
```

So if you want space on the right, the padding definition should be :

```
vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));
```

Comment: still, when i make the window larger it creates another empty column. can i fix that?

Comment: can i make the existing columns be wider when i make the window bigger? how? @ItachiUchiha

Comment: You can use `table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);` to avoid the extra column.